# Compile project for both x86 and x64 from command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I am making this question in regards to compiling both x64 & x86 builds at the same time. I am using MSVS 2012 ultimate and I have a 64-bit and 32-bit configuration for my EXE. I want to compile them both at the same time via the command line. Can someone give me a pseudo-translation on how I can approach this?

Comment: Compile one, then the other.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen k.